# Spring Boot with log4j2 not working when change default properties file name

Tags: spring-boot, properties, log4j2

I have Spring Boot application and I want to use log4j2 instead of logback. I've already done all the necessary steps to exclude spring-boot-starter-logging from spring-boot-starter-web and added spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency.
When I add log4j2.properties file under resources folder it works correct and I can see logs.
But when I change file name to, lets say log4j2-demo.properties and set logging.config=classpath:log4j2-demo.properties nothing prints to console. For testing purpose I've set different name for lo4gj2 file in logging.config and it gives error with file not found and I think logging.config property actually working and reading my properties file.

**application.properties** file:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

**application-dev.properties** file:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-demo.properties
```

**log4j2** properties file:

```
status=debug
name=PropertiesConfig
#
filters=threshold
#
filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=debug
#
appenders=console
#
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#
rootLogger.level=info
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

my application structure:

```
src
  main
    java
    resources
       application.properties
       application-dev.properties
       log4j2-demo.properties
```

**pom.xml** :

```
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zalando/logbook-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j 2.13.0 you can use profiles to define log4j 2 system properties in your spring configuration. So you could have:

**application-dev.properties**

```
log4j2.configurationFile=log4j2-demo.properties.
```

Log4j 2.13.0 also supports placing the log4j 2 configuration file in Spring Cloud Config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer applies to this question, but in my case, I added the resource to the build configuration on my `pom.xml`, e.g.

```xml
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include> <!-- or **/*.properties -->
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
...
```

Of course, I excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

```xml
...
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
...
```

Although, I used the default log4j2 file name `log4j2.xml` and the step configuration on the `application.yml` was not required, I mean this configuration `logging.config=classpath:log4j2-demo.properties`